# Prisma Self Relation, How to Loop

Tags: mysql, node.js, prisma

I tried to build post categories (like a Wordpress have) where it have multi-dimensional level or parents-child level. I try to generate with Prisma and seems lost to figure how to loop.

```
model post_category {
  id                  BigInt               @id @default(autoincrement())
  name_category       String               @db.Text
  slug                String               @db.Text
  parent_id           BigInt?
  updated_at          DateTime             @default(now()) @db.Timestamp(0)
  post_category       post_category?       @relation("post_categoryTopost_category", fields: [parent_id], references: [id], onDelete: NoAction, onUpdate: NoAction, map: "self_parentId_id")
  other_post_category post_category[]      @relation("post_categoryTopost_category")
  post_category_list  post_category_list[]

  @@index([parent_id], map: "parent_id")
}
```

```
await prisma.post_category.findMany({
        include: {
          other_post_category: { <== Is there a way to loop instead of manually add include?
            include:{
              other_post_category: {
                include: {
                  other_post_category: {
                    include: {
                      other_post_category: true
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        },
        where: {
          parent_id: {
              equals: null
          }
        },
        orderBy: {
          name_category: 'desc',
        }
      })
```

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "name_category": "No Category",
        "parent_id": null,
        "other_post_category": [
            {
                "id": "2",
                "name_category": "Tes",
                "parent_id": "1",
                "other_post_category": [
                    {
                        "id": "4",
                        "name_category": "Tes 2",
                        "parent_id": "2",
                        "other_post_category": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

For now my solution just keep repeating that 'include' line manually. So, any idea to that looping? Thanks

Comment: I found that Prisma does not support loop self-relation or recursive https://github.com/prisma/prisma/issues/3725. Hope it will update in future.